# Tar archive parser - custom implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm learning python and for educational purposes I implemented [tar archive parser](https://github.com/lukascode/tar-parser). I'm not beginner programmer. I would like to receive some feedback and tips about code, what can I improve, what could be done better and so on.

Implementation:

**tar.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io
import os
import sys
import math
import json

class Tar:

    BLOCK_SIZE = 512

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        if not file_path or len(file_path) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Bad file path")
        self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self):
        self.input_stream = open(self.file_path, "rb")
        self.headers = []
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def close(self):
        if self.input_stream:
            self.input_stream.close()

    def get_all_files(self):
        self.__scan()
        return list(map(
            lambda f: FileSnapshot(f.file_name, f.file_size, f.file_mode, f.flag), 
            self.headers
        ))

    def extract_file(self, file_name, target_folder=os.getcwd()):
        if not file_name or len(file_name) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Bad file name")
        if not target_folder or len(target_folder) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Bad target folder")
        self.__scan()
        result = list(filter(
            lambda fh: fh.flag == 0 and fh.file_name == file_name, 
            self.headers
        ))
        if len(result) == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("File '{}' not found".format(file_name))
        fh = result[0]
        leaf = os.path.basename(fh.file_name)
        f_path = os.path.join(target_folder, leaf)
        self.__extract(fh, f_path)

    def extract_all(self, target_folder=os.getcwd()):
        if not target_folder or len(target_folder) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Bad target folder")
        self.__scan()
        for fh in self.headers:
            f_path = os.path.join(target_folder, fh.file_name)
            if fh.flag == 5: # if directory
                os.makedirs(f_path, exist_ok=True)
            elif fh.flag == 0: # if regular file
                parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(f_path))
                os.makedirs(parent, exist_ok=True)
                self.__extract(fh, f_path)


    def __extract(self, fh, file_name):
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            if fh.file_size > 0:
                total = 0
                bytes_left = fh.file_size
                self.input_stream.seek(fh.offset, 0)
                while bytes_left > 0:
                    data = self.input_stream.read(Tar.BLOCK_SIZE)
                    data = data[:bytes_left]
                    f.write(data)
                    bytes_left -= len(data)

    def __scan(self): # iterate over headers
        if len(self.headers) == 0:
            while True:
                block = self.input_stream.read(Tar.BLOCK_SIZE)
                if len(block) < Tar.BLOCK_SIZE:
                    break
                h = self.__get_file_header(block)
                if not len(h.magic) > 0:
                    break
                # ommit regular file bytes
                if h.flag == 0:
                    h.set_offset(self.input_stream.tell())
                    if h.file_size > 0:
                        if h.file_size % Tar.BLOCK_SIZE != 0:
                            bytes_to_skeep = math.ceil(h.file_size / Tar.BLOCK_SIZE) * Tar.BLOCK_SIZE
                        else:
                            bytes_to_skeep = h.file_size
                        self.input_stream.seek(bytes_to_skeep, 1)
                self.headers.append(h)


    def __get_file_header(self, block):
        try:
            file_name = self.__get_file_name(block)
            file_mode = self.__get_file_mode(block)
            uid = self.__get_uid(block)
            gid = self.__get_gid(block)
            file_size = self.__get_file_size(block)
            mtime = self.__get_mtime(block)
            chksum = self.__get_chksum(block)
            type_flag = self.__get_type_flag(block)
            linkname = self.__get_linkname(block)
            magic = self.__get_magic(block)
            version = self.__get_version(block)
            uname = self.__get_uname(block)
            gname = self.__get_gname(block)
            devmajor = self.__get_devmajor(block)
            devminor = self.__get_devminor(block)
            prefix = self.__get_prefix(block)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Broken file") from e
        header = FileHeader(file_name, file_size, file_mode, uid, gid, 
            mtime, chksum, type_flag, linkname, magic, version, 
            uname, gname, devmajor, devminor, prefix)
        return header


    def __get_file_name(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 0, 100
        fname = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        fname = fname[0:fname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return fname

    def __get_file_mode(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 100, 8
        mode = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        mode = mode[:mode.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return mode

    def __get_uid(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 108, 8
        uid = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        uid = uid[:uid.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return uid

    def __get_gid(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 116, 8
        gid = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        gid = gid[:gid.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return gid

    def __get_file_size(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 124, 12
        size = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        size = size[:size.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        if len(size) > 0:
            size = int(size, 8)
        else:
            size = 0
        return size

    def __get_mtime(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 136, 12
        mtime = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        mtime = mtime[:len(mtime)-1]
        mtime = mtime[:mtime.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        if len(mtime) > 0:
            mtime = int(mtime, 8)
        else:
            mtime = 0
        return mtime

    def __get_chksum(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 148, 8
        chksum = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        chksum = chksum[:chksum.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        if len(chksum) > 0:
            chksum = int(chksum)
        else:
            chksum = 0
        return chksum

    def __get_type_flag(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 156, 1
        flag = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        if flag == b'\x00':
            flag = 0
        elif flag == b'x':
            flag = 11
        else:
            flag = int(flag)
        return flag

    def __get_linkname(self, block): # string (applicable if type_flag = 1 or 2)
        offset, size = 157, 100
        linkname = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        return linkname[:linkname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()

    def __get_magic(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 257, 6
        magic = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        magic = magic[:magic.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return magic

    def __get_version(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 263, 2
        version = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        version = version[:len(version)-1].decode().strip()
        return version

    def __get_uname(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 265, 32
        uname = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        uname = uname[:uname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return uname

    def __get_gname(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 297, 32
        gname = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        gname = gname[:gname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return gname

    def __get_devmajor(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 329, 8
        devmajor = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        devmajor = devmajor[:devmajor.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return devmajor

    def __get_devminor(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 337, 8
        devminor = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        devminor = devminor[:devminor.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return devminor

    def __get_prefix(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 345, 155
        prefix = self.__get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        prefix = prefix[:prefix.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return prefix

    def __get_block_data(self, block, offset, size):
        return block[offset:offset+size]

class FileSnapshot:
    def __init__(self, file_name, file_size, file_mode, flag):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file_size = file_size
        self.file_mode = file_mode
        self.flag = flag

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.file_name

class FileHeader:
    def __init__(self, file_name, file_size, file_mode, uid, gid, mtime, 
    chksum, flag, linkname, magic, version, uname, gname, devmajor, devminor, prefix):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file_size = file_size
        self.file_mode = file_mode
        self.uid = uid
        self.gid = gid
        self.mtime = mtime
        self.chksum = chksum
        self.flag = flag
        self.linkname = linkname
        self.magic = magic
        self.version = version
        self.uname = uname
        self.gname = gname
        self.devmajor = devmajor
        self.devminor = devminor
        self.prefix = prefix

    def set_offset(self, offset):
        self.offset = offset 


def usage():
    u = """
    Usage:
    tar.py <archive.tar> --list                 List all files in the archive
    tar.py <archive.tar> --extract-all          Extract all files from the archive
    tar.py <archive.tar> --extract <file>       Extract single file from the archive
    """
    print(u)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) > 2:
            archive = sys.argv[1]
            operation = sys.argv[2]
            with Tar(archive) as t:
                if operation == "--list":
                    files = t.get_all_files()
                    for f in files:
                        print(f)
                elif operation == "--extract-all":
                    t.extract_all()
                elif operation == "--extract":
                    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
                        file_name = sys.argv[3]
                        t.extract_file(file_name)
                    else:
                        usage()
        else:
            usage()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: {}".format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)
```

**tartest.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
import tar
import os

class TarTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_all_files(self):
        # given
        with tar.Tar("tartest.tar") as t:

            # when
            files = t.get_all_files()

            # then
            self.assertTrue(len(files) == 5)
            self.assertTrue(self.containsFile(files, "tartest/a.txt"))
            self.assertTrue(self.containsFile(files, "tartest/b.txt"))
            self.assertTrue(self.containsFile(files, "tartest/foo/c.txt"))

    def test_extract_file(self):
        # given
        with tar.Tar("tartest.tar") as t:

            # when
            t.extract_file("tartest/a.txt")
            t.extract_file("tartest/foo/c.txt")

            # then
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile("a.txt"))
            self.assertTrue(self.fileContains("a.txt", "This is file a"))

            self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile("c.txt"))
            self.assertTrue(self.fileContains("c.txt", "This is file c"))

            os.remove("a.txt")
            os.remove("c.txt")

    def test_extract_all(self):
        # given
        with tar.Tar("tartest.tar") as t:

            # when
            t.extract_all()

            # then
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isdir("tartest"))
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isdir("tartest/foo"))
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile("tartest/a.txt"))
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile("tartest/b.txt"))
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile("tartest/foo/c.txt"))

            os.system("rm -rf tartest")

    def containsFile(self, files, file_name):
        for f in files:
            if f.file_name == file_name:
                return True
        return False

    def fileContains(self, file_name, content):
        with open(file_name) as f:
            return content == f.read().splitlines()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Oh, one last thing: I tried using your code to unzip a file tar'ed with 7zip, and it failed trying to convert the flag (b'L', which is a vendor flag) to an int; you might want your code to fail more gracefully in the case of an unrecognized flag (and use a str flag instead of an int one)

Answer (score 4):

I can offer some tips for making your code more pythonic.

#### General

- It's good practice to add a docstring for each module, class, and documented function.
- Imports `io` and `json` are unused.
- In the `Tar.__extract` method, the variable `total` is unused.

#### `class Tar`

- `not file_path or len(file_path) == 0`: If the user inputs an empty string, `not file_path` is sufficient (and `None` is not a possible value unless input manually). More to the point, you are not exactly detecting a "bad file path". You could use [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) for a more robust check. Alternatively, don't validate the path at all, and consider a `try... except OSError` block in your `__enter__` method; this will [avoid race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575508/10601881). (You perform similar checks in `extract_file` and `extract_all` that can also be changed.)
- You have an `__enter__` method and an `__exit__` method, which allows your class to be used with a context-manager, excellent! However, you also provide a `close` function, without providing a corresponding `open` function, which means that `close` could never be reasonably called by the user. Eliminate `close` or add `open`.
- You invoke name-mangling by using double-underscores on methods like `__extract`; this is fine to prevent truly "private" data members from clashing with those from a superclass or subclass, but on methods it makes inheriting from your class (say, to extend it with logging features) unnecessarily difficult. To mark a member as "private", [a single leading underscore is enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456865/10601881).
- Similarly, in the interest of being able to subclass your class, you should consider `self.BLOCK_SIZE` instead of `Tar.BLOCK_SIZE` (though maybe this is a constant of the tar format?).
- `list(map(...))`: It's generally more clear to replace this with a list comprehension (and as opposed to `lambda`, sometimes [more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948713/10601881)):

  ```py
  def get_all_files(self):
      self._scan()
      return [FileSnapshot(f.file_name, f.file_size, f.file_mode, f.flag) for f in self.headers]
  ```
- `list(filter(...))`: To get the first match, it's generally better to use a generator comprehension:

  ```
  def extract_file(...):
      ...
      try:
          result = next(fh for fh in self.headers if fh.flag == 0 and fh.file_name == file_name)
      except StopIteration:
          raise RuntimeError("File '{}' not found".format(file_name))
      ...
  ```

#### `class FileSnapshot`, `class FileHeader`

- There is a lot of boilerplate code here, that could be eliminated with *e.g.* the [`@dataclass` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

  ```py
  from dataclasses import dataclass
  ...
  @dataclass
  class FileSnapshot:
      file_name : str
      file_size : int
      ...
  ```
- `__repr__` methods are generally supposed to [return code that will reproduce the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/10601881); consider renaming this method to `__str__` instead.

#### `__main__`

- Take advantage of the standard library [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module. For example, it makes extending your `--extract` switch to extract multiple files easier, provides error checking and usage strings, and can be used to initialize `archive` as a `Tar` automatically.

  ```py
  from argparse import ArgumentParser
  ...
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      parser = ArgumentParser(description='.tar archive extractor')
      parser.add_argument('archive', type=Tar, help='...')
      group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
      group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true', help='List files')
      group.add_argument('--extract-all', action='store_true', help='Extract all')
      group.add_argument('--extract', nargs='+', help='Extract some')
      args = parser.parse_args()
      with args.archive as t:
          ...
  ```

#### Code

Here's my take on your code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''TODO: docstring'''

import os
import math
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Tar:
    '''TODO docstring'''
    BLOCK_SIZE = 512

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.input_stream = None
        self.headers = []

    def __enter__(self):
        self.input_stream = open(self.file_path, "rb")
        self.headers = []
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        if self.input_stream is not None:
            self.input_stream.close()

    def get_all_files(self):
        '''TODO docstring'''
        self._scan()
        return [FileSnapshot(f.file_name, f.file_size, f.file_mode, f.flag) 
                for f in self.headers]

    def extract_file(self, file_name, target_folder=os.getcwd()):
        '''TODO docstring'''
        self._scan()
        try:
            fh = next(fh for fh in self.headers if fh.flag == 0 and fh.file_name == file_name)
        except StopIteration:
            raise RuntimeError("File '{}' not found".format(file_name))
        leaf = os.path.basename(fh.file_name)
        f_path = os.path.join(target_folder, leaf)
        self._extract(fh, f_path)

    def extract_all(self, target_folder=os.getcwd()):
        '''TODO docstring'''
        self._scan()
        for fh in self.headers:
            f_path = os.path.join(target_folder, fh.file_name)
            if fh.flag == 5: # if directory
                os.makedirs(f_path, exist_ok=True)
            elif fh.flag == 0: # if regular file
                parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(f_path))
                os.makedirs(parent, exist_ok=True)
                self._extract(fh, f_path)


    def _extract(self, fh, file_name):
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            if fh.file_size > 0:
                bytes_left = fh.file_size
                self.input_stream.seek(fh.offset, 0)
                while bytes_left > 0:
                    data = self.input_stream.read(Tar.BLOCK_SIZE)
                    data = data[:bytes_left]
                    f.write(data)
                    bytes_left -= len(data)

    def _scan(self): # iterate over headers
        if len(self.headers) == 0:
            while True:
                block = self.input_stream.read(Tar.BLOCK_SIZE)
                if len(block) < Tar.BLOCK_SIZE:
                    break
                h = self._get_file_header(block)
                if not len(h.magic) > 0:
                    break
                # omit regular file bytes
                if h.flag == 0:
                    h.offset = self.input_stream.tell()
                    if h.file_size > 0:
                        if h.file_size % Tar.BLOCK_SIZE != 0:
                            bytes_to_skeep = math.ceil(h.file_size / Tar.BLOCK_SIZE) * Tar.BLOCK_SIZE
                        else:
                            bytes_to_skeep = h.file_size
                        self.input_stream.seek(bytes_to_skeep, 1)
                self.headers.append(h)


    def _get_file_header(self, block):
        try:
            return FileHeader(
                self._get_file_name(block),
                self._get_file_size(block),
                self._get_file_mode(block),
                self._get_uid(block),
                self._get_gid(block),
                self._get_mtime(block),
                self._get_chksum(block),
                self._get_type_flag(block),
                self._get_linkname(block),
                self._get_magic(block),
                self._get_version(block),
                self._get_uname(block),
                self._get_gname(block),
                self._get_devmajor(block),
                self._get_devminor(block),
                self._get_prefix(block)
            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Broken file") from e


    def _get_file_name(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 0, 100
        fname = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        fname = fname[0:fname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return fname

    def _get_file_mode(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 100, 8
        mode = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        mode = mode[:mode.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return mode

    def _get_uid(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 108, 8
        uid = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        uid = uid[:uid.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return uid

    def _get_gid(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 116, 8
        gid = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        gid = gid[:gid.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return gid

    def _get_file_size(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 124, 12
        size = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        size = size[:size.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        if len(size) > 0:
            size = int(size, 8)
        else:
            size = 0
        return size

    def _get_mtime(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 136, 12
        mtime = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        mtime = mtime[:len(mtime)-1]
        mtime = mtime[:mtime.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        if len(mtime) > 0:
            mtime = int(mtime, 8)
        else:
            mtime = 0
        return mtime

    def _get_chksum(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 148, 8
        chksum = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        chksum = chksum[:chksum.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        if len(chksum) > 0:
            chksum = int(chksum)
        else:
            chksum = 0
        return chksum

    def _get_type_flag(self, block): # int
        offset, size = 156, 1
        flag = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        if flag == b'\x00':
            flag = 0
        elif flag == b'x':
            flag = 11
        else:
            flag = int(flag)
        return flag

    def _get_linkname(self, block): # string (applicable if type_flag = 1 or 2)
        offset, size = 157, 100
        linkname = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        return linkname[:linkname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()

    def _get_magic(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 257, 6
        magic = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        magic = magic[:magic.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return magic

    def _get_version(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 263, 2
        version = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        version = version[:len(version)-1].decode().strip()
        return version

    def _get_uname(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 265, 32
        uname = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        uname = uname[:uname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return uname

    def _get_gname(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 297, 32
        gname = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        gname = gname[:gname.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return gname

    def _get_devmajor(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 329, 8
        devmajor = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        devmajor = devmajor[:devmajor.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return devmajor

    def _get_devminor(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 337, 8
        devminor = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        devminor = devminor[:devminor.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return devminor

    def _get_prefix(self, block): # string
        offset, size = 345, 155
        prefix = self._get_block_data(block, offset, size)
        prefix = prefix[:prefix.find(b'\x00')].decode().strip()
        return prefix

    def _get_block_data(self, block, offset, size):
        return block[offset:offset+size]

@dataclass
class FileSnapshot:
    '''TODO: docstring'''
    file_name: str
    file_size: int
    file_mode: str
    flag: int

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name

@dataclass
class FileHeader:
    '''TODO: docstring'''
    file_name: str
    file_size: int
    file_mode: str
    uid: str
    gid: str
    mtime: int
    chksum: int
    flag: int
    linkname: str 
    magic: str
    version: str
    uname: str
    gname: str
    devmajor: str
    devminor: str
    prefix: str
    offset: int = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def main():
        from argparse import ArgumentParser
        parser = ArgumentParser(description='.tar archive extractor')
        parser.add_argument('archive', type=Tar,
                            help='The tar archive file')
        group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
        group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true', 
                           help='List all files in the archive')
        group.add_argument('--extract-all', action='store_true', 
                           help='Extract all files from the archive')
        group.add_argument('--extract', nargs='+', dest='files',
                           help='Extract specified files from the archive')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        with args.archive as t:
            if args.list:
                files = t.get_all_files()
                for file in files:
                    print(file)
            elif args.extract_all:
                t.extract_all()
            else:
                for file in args.files:
                    t.extract_file(file)

    main()
```

Comment: All the `_get_*` could be probably done easier by having a `_get_block_data` that truncates to the null byte and decodes and strips the value and then you can have e.g. `_get_linkname = functools.partialmethod(_get_block_data, offset=157, size=100)`. This way you only need to spell out the two where you need to do additional checking. Or maybe even better, save the sizes in a class variable and iterate over the `block` in chunks of varying sizes.

Comment: It's true, the get methods are not very DRY; even just adding the find/slice/decode/strip portion to `_get_block_data` would save on boilerplate, or maybe factoring it into a `_get_block_str` since `_get_type_flag` exceptionally doesn't use it